# How to get a week's view history of the job i.e running from Autosys Job Schedular?

Tags: sql-server-2005, scheduling, console-application, scheduled-tasks, autosys

### SCENARIO:

Previously Jobs are scheduled to run from SQL Server.

In the SQL Server database the jobs ran as per their start times mentioned.

All the operations such as stopping the running job,starting the job are done by right clicking on the job.

#### View history for the job (status,starttime and endtime of the job) is done by right clicking the job and selecting view history.

By doing above thing we used to get details of entire week.

### CHANGE IMPLEMENTED

The jobs running in the SQL Server database are now triggered from Autosys Console.

operations like starting the job,stopping the job are now done through Autosys.

Controlling job behaviour is done through Autosys.

### PROBLEM

Could not get the view history of the job for **entire week**.

If we go for view history of any **one particular job** in the autosys console only the before day job execution details are given(status,start and end time) are given.

#### Is there any way in autosys job schedular console to get the job history of any particular job for the entire week?

Please help.

Comment: You realy dont need to shout, we can read your question... All caps are seen as shouting. http://email.about.com/b/2006/06/14/writing-in-all-caps-is-like-shouting.htm

Comment: ha ha ok got it.
next time will not repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out JAWS from http://www.termalabs.com. It will provide an answer to your question and a whole lot more for your AutoSys environment.